# Query to get top 5 users by total month sales amount

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I was hoping you could help me figure this out. I would like to run a `query` that would search a table and all it's rows and the date matches the current month. Then return the `user_id`. What I am trying to achieve is gathering the top 5 user id's under this `query`.

How can I change this to find the top 5 for the current month? I am usually able to figure out my queries but this one has me stumped.

This is all I have at the moment.

```
$top = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT sum(amount) AS total FROM sales WHERE status = 'S' AND MONTH(date) = 1");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($top))
         {

           $userid = $row['0'];

         }
```

Update:

```
$top = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT user_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) total 
        FROM sales 
        WHERE status = 'S' 
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
        AND YEAR(date)  =  YEAR(CURDATE())
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) q
        ORDER BY total DESC
        LIMIT 5");

           while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($top))
                {
                   $topsales[] = $row['0'];
                }

    foreach($topsales as $topsale) {
            echo $topsale;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired output? `SUM(status)` doesn't make any sense. Maybe you meant some other column (e.g. `amount` or `total`...)?

Comment: Yah I did mean amount, sorry. Let me update that.

Comment: your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a query like this?

```sql
SELECT user_id
  FROM
(
  SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) total 
    FROM sales 
   WHERE status = 'S' 
     AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
     AND YEAR(date)  =  YEAR(CURDATE())
  GROUP BY user_id
) q
 ORDER BY total DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

or just

```sql
SELECT user_id 
  FROM sales 
 WHERE status = 'S' 
   AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
   AND YEAR(date)  =  YEAR(CURDATE())
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Here is **[SLQFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366b8/9)** demo

Note: *using `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions will prevent MySql from using any index you might have on `date` column*

---

Now your php code might look like this

```php
$db  = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Cannot connect'); // TODO: better error handling
}
$sql = "SELECT user_id 
          FROM sales 
         WHERE status = 'S' 
           AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
           AND YEAR(date)  =  YEAR(CURDATE())
         GROUP BY user_id
         ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC
         LIMIT 5";

$topsales = array();

if ($query = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($user_id);

    while ($query->fetch()) {
        $topsales[] = $user_id;
    }
    $query->close();
} else {
    die('Unable to prepare: ' . $db->error); // TODO: better error handling
}
$db->close();

foreach ($topsales as $topsale) {
    echo $topsale . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this answer. This looks promising. Can you see my updated code and revise yours accordingly. Sorry about that.

Comment: I would also need to figure out the current month to run in the query.

Comment: Awesome. Will I run a `while statement` like in my example? Also, is that `q` a typo? Thanks

Comment: @user2491130 Yes you need `while` since the query returns a resulset of up to 5 records. Now `q` is not a typo it's an alias for the subquery and is mandatory in MySql. Take a look at sqlfiddle demo that I provided in updated answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I just updated my code above. I tried this but it did not echo any user id's. If you see an error in there please let me know. I'm gonna study the code closer. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem with your php code is that you overwrite a value of `$topsales`. Instead you need to make it an array. And then push values into it while iterating over the resultset from `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Yah I noticed that and changed it to `$topsales[] = $row['0'];` but that still did not work.

Comment: You've been a big help. I'm going to select your answer and try to figure out the foreach issue. Thanks

Comment: @user2491130 I'm glad I could help :) See updated answer for a php code example

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. It was my fault, I forgot this is July and my DB only had June in it. Working great now!